# How to write this in TeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, arrows, tikz-arrows, mathtools

[image: Task]

Hi, can you help me to do this task.

Comment: Things like https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/ would help. It is literally something along the lines of `\large` and `\huge`.

Comment: thanks, but how to write this arrows before "Difficult"

Comment: [Here](https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) you can find a list of symbols that can be done with LaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). I suggest you search this site for `\tikzmark` as that would be ideal for this.  Also, it is helpful if you show what you can do in terms of a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  For instance, can you at type in the desired text with the desired size and location? While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: `$\gg$` or `\guillemotright` or `\Gt` with `boisik` or `stix` packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possibility using a `matrix of nodes` for the first “line”. `matrix of nodes` is a style from the `matrix` Ti*k*Z library. I let you add the cyrillic characters, as I am not competent in this area. ;-)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Use the 'text depth' key to tune the depth of the matrix
% nodes, and thus where the arrow tips arrive.
\matrix (mymat) [matrix of nodes, column sep=0.2em, nodes={text depth=3ex}]
  {
    Just & data & \guillemotright\guillemotright\guillemotright
         & |(diff)|\Huge \textbf{Difficult} & |(easy)| \LARGE\textit{Easy}
         & |(data)|data\\
  };

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={outer ysep=0.2ex, align=center}]
  \node (some) [below right=1cm and 0.5cm of diff.south]
    {Some\\ \textcolor{red!80!black}{text}};
  \node (other) [below=1cm of data]
    {\textcolor{red!80!black}{Other}\\ text};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[every path/.append style={draw, -latex}]
  \path (some) -- (diff);
  \path (some) -- (easy);
  \path (other) -- (data);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much!